# tkinter messagebox not showing on Windows taskbar

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a Python application, and would like to messagebox to notify the user of an error, and it behaves the way I want in Linux (tested on Mint and Ubuntu), but on Windows it doesn't create an application on the taskbar, so it gets lost. I could also have it stick to the front, but that's also a little obnoxious. Here's what I'm working with:

```
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox

root = Tk()
messagebox.showerror("Oh please work oh please work oh please", "Show up on taskbar! ... *sigh")
root.withdraw()
```

Comment: Such a behavior, that you're wonder about are transient windows, thoose share the taskbar positions. On Windows you can treat a `tk_messageBox` as a wrapper around a native `MessageBox` function, and this one is a transient and modal window by default. If you want it to be a separate thing on the task bar - you can call it manually as a non-transient  via `ctypes` built-in.

Comment: @CommonSense that sounds like the way to go! Unfortunately, I don't know a lot about ctypes or how to create a wrapper around MessageBox. I'm looking into it now, but if you were to give some code to get me started I would be happy to accept a working answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's elaborate what *transient* window is on root-toplevel example.

By default `Toplevel` appears as non-transient, but, thanks to [`transient`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method) method, we're able to fix that.
Here's a snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text='root').pack()
top = tk.Toplevel(root)
tk.Label(top, text='toplevel').pack()
# uncomment to make top transient
# top.transient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Ok, now we know something about it and, especially, the fact about taskbar behaviour on Windows.

But what about solutions? There's some, and your approach is OK, let's modify it a littlebit:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg

root = tk.Tk()

if root._windowingsystem == 'win32':
    # windows showerror
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.iconify()
    msg.showerror("Oh please work oh please work oh please", "Show up on taskbar! ... *sigh", parent=top)
    top.destroy()
else:
    # non-windows showerror
    msg.showerror("Oh please work oh please work oh please", "Show up on taskbar! ... *sigh")

root.destroy()
```

If you crawl under the hood of `tkinter` - you will see that `parent` parameter isn't a really optional, and `tkinter` treats the `Tk` as a parent if you pass `None`. But we can feed it with dummy-Toplevel, hence our message will be *transient* to `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` instance.

Also, as I said in comments, we can call native [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as msg
import ctypes

MB_OK = 0x0
ICON_STOP = 0x10


root = tk.Tk()

# non-transient app-wide version
native_showerror = lambda: ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Oh please work oh please work oh please",
                                                            "Show up on taskbar! ... *sigh", MB_OK | ICON_STOP)
# transient version if we pass hWnd of the root window
native_showerror_transient = lambda: ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(root.winfo_id(),
                                                                      "Oh please work oh please work oh please",
                                                                      "Show up on taskbar! ... *sigh", MB_OK | ICON_STOP)

if root._windowingsystem == 'win32':
    # windows showerror
    root.update_idletasks()
    native_showerror()

else:
    # non-windows showerror
    msg.showerror("Oh please work oh please work oh please", "Show up on taskbar! ... *sigh")

root.mainloop()
```

While it isn't count as a work-around for me (we don't adopt to tkinter, we do what we want to do), it's some sort of reinventing the wheel, because this stuff is already implemented under the hood. However, it's more flexible in terms of apperance, but it isn't a point of your question.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept - school happened! Anyways, this gives the behavior I'm looking for. I can look into the why later

Answer (score 0):

So one work-around that I found was instead of withdrawing the root window, I just set the invisibility or root to 0, and then minimized it to highly decrease the already-low probability of pressing the invisible exit button. Then I checked if the OS was running Windows, and if not, then I withdraw root.

```
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox
import sys

root = Tk()  # We need a main window
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
root.wm_state('iconic')
if not sys.platform.lower().startswith("win"):
    root.withdraw()
messagebox.showerror("Oops!", "Sorry! Could not connect to the server!")
root.withdraw()
```

Note: Windows and Linux are the only two platforms I'm supporting, but I'm speculating this would work on Mac as well. Please let me know if you find differently